# Read mysqli query result into multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I have a code to read data from MySQL database based on user input sequence, and I want all the result to be stored into a multi-dimensional array to be used in later part. However, **the code will only store the last array but not every array.** Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($up_gene) ; $i ++){
    $geneName = $up_gene[$i];
    $mysql = "SELECT * FROM clmap WHERE GeneID = '$geneName'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $mysql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result , MYSQLI_NUM);
    $up_temp[$i] = $row;
}
```

Data in my database would be as followed:

```
GeneID  | 17_AAG | HUTYG | A_770897 | AICAR | ...
-------------------------------------------------
FR2L1   | 1390   | 6746  | 4316     | 1051  | ...
ALDH1A1 | 288    | 7622  | 12       | 98867 | ...

# other rows is similar to above #
```

If I input a list of `GeneID` for example `FR2L1`, `ALDH1A1`, `ABAT`, `AAAS`,
the output array will only have value for last array which in this case is `$up_temp[3]`, the rest from `$up_temp[0]` to `$up_temp[2]` are empty. There are millions of rows in the database, but I will only need to select user's input `GeneID`.

Output of `print_r($up_temp[3])`

> Array ( [0] => F2RL1 [1] => 1390 [2] => 6764 [3] => 4316 [4] => 1051
>   [5] => 11654 [6] => 1871 [7] => 8863 [8] => 1245 [9] => 6438 [10] =>
>   12693 [11] => 7525 [12] => 10372 [13] => 10625 [14] => 7114 [15] =>
>   12180 [16] => 2760 [17] => 375 [18] => 12525 [19] => 2828 [20] => 6938
>   [21] => 5926 [22] => 8906 [23] => 9372 [24] => 6341 [25] => 1427 [26]
>   => 3858 [27] => 1194 [28] => 3510 [29] => 2462 [30] => 3301 [31] => 1909 [32] => 3816 [33] => 8901 [34] => 5361 [35] => 2711 [36] => 5294
>   [37] => 6138 [38] => 10272 [39] => 9893 [40] => 1205 [41] => 10868
>   [42] => 3016 [43] => 1601 [44] => 315 [45] => 2577 [46] => 6226 [47]
>   => 274 [48] => 1573 [49] => 2681 [50] => 1447 [51] => 5375 [52] => 1381 [53] => 6405 [54] => 11033 [55] => 7915 [56] => 8293 [57] => 3446
>   [58] => 231 [59] => 9772 [60] => 4684 [61] => 432 [62] => 1815 [63] =>
>   10904 [64] => 41 [65] => 4647 [66] => 3238 [67] => 5488 [68] => 2340
>   [69] => 4925 [70] => 2513 [71] => 911 [72] => 3736 [73] => 6593 [74]
>   => 1441 [75] => 3098 [76] => 2976 [77] => 4665 [78] => 8056 [79] => 10717 [80] => 53 [81] => 4159 [82] => 9920 [83] => 5673 [84] => 12146
>   [85] => 2072 [86] => 4753 [87] => 9678 [88] => 6811 [89] => 7519 [90]
>   => 10708 [91] => 1215 [92] => 6837 [93] => 6817 [94] => 6085 [95] => 7160 [96] => 9059 [97] => 7729 [98] => 5330 [99] => 179 [100] => 1020
>   [101] => 8672 [102] => 9971 [103] => 7189 [104] => 2307 [105] => 2849
>   [106] => 4897 [107] => 1229 [108] => 11588 [109] => 1923 [110] =>
>   12715 [111] => 2099 [112] => 12035 [113] => 4062 [114] => 1416 [115]
>   => 547 [116] => 1915 [117] => 7689 [118] => 6641 [119] => 11312 [120] => 7079 [121] => 8564 [122] => 2156 [123] => 539 [124] => 4850 [125] => 10205 [126] => 1756 [127] => 1266 [128] => 3468 [129] => 7341 [130] => 8809 [131] => 11949 [132] => 10126 [133] => 3436 [134] => 8066 [135] => 3116 [136] => 4155 [137] => 1637 [138] => 1717 [139] => 2045
>   [140] => 7511 )

Output of `print_r($up_temp[0])` to `print_r($up_temp[2])` : empty

---

UPDATE: it turns out that my `$up_gene` variable are not properly entered, just realized there are space behind each variables which causes MySQL query return empty for first few variables. The code above do works as expected.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array as mysqli_fetch_assoc($result,$result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
$up_temp = array();
$sql = "select * from clmap where GeneID in(".implode(",",$up_gene).");";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result , MYSQLI_NUM)){
    $up_temp[] = $row;
}
```

Implode the array `$up_gene` so that all ids are a comma seperated string. Then use mysql `in` to fetch all rows that have one of you ids. At least run a `while` loop and store the $row arrays into the multi-dimensional array $up_temp

Comment: turns out to be my `$up_gene` variable problem. Your code help me to improve my code, so I accept yours as the answer. Thanks.